# Add new rows to a DataTable after clearing it

Tags: c#, datatable, dataset

I need a DataTable (not coupled to a database) to add new rows after I cleared it.
My code looks like this:

```
            if (DialogResult.OK == openRaw.ShowDialog())
            {
                foreach (String file in openRaw.FileNames)
                {              
                        table1.Rows.Add((seconds * 0.00390625), RPM, map, (tps * 0.1), ((mat - 320) * 0.05555), ((clt - 320) * 0.05555), (PW1 * 0.000666), (PW2 * 0.000666), (advance * 0.1), (knock * 0.1), (RPM / 100), (Baro * 0.1), (AFR * 0.1), (bat * 0.1));
                        table1.AcceptChanges();
                        CreateCSVFile(table1, filename);

                }
                table1.Rows.Clear();
                table1.AcceptChanges();
                }
            }
```

The first file goes fine, the table is cleared, but with the next files the table isn't refilled again with new rows.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are clearing the table as soon as you have filled it, is that desired? You are doing nothing with it.

Comment: Note: AcceptChanges shouldn't be required unless you're using the table to manage multiple states at once.

Comment: what actually do you want to do with your code?

Comment: This definitely won't compile

Comment: @TimSchmelter I added a line above. The table is put in a csv file. I only typed the part of the code which I have a problem with ;)

Comment: @Felix: Why don't you use `table1 = new DataTable()` instead of `table1.Clear()`? However, in either case it seems to be better to create it before_ you use it, not after you have used it.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I've declared `DataTable table1 = new DataTable();` at the beginning of the code. I do not have to create each time, correct?

Comment: @Felix: The constructor is more efficient than `Clear`. Apart from that, you are showing pseudo code where you add the rows. How are yu adding the rows?

Comment: @TimSchmelter If I use `DataTable table1 = new DataTable();` at the beginning of the foreach loop I get the same result as with the code I posted above. As for adding of the rows, see the code above, the different items I'm adding are declared as `short` ;)

Comment: @Felix: Are you sure that there is no exception, have you used the debugger to see what happens? I don't know what you are adding there, also, the variable `file` that you are looping is never used. The `AcceptChanges` is redundant, it does nothing here.

Comment: @TimSchmelter OK its really time for me to get some sleep now... I was using BinaryReader in combination with a loop to read the file and add the rows. But I forgot to reset the counter I use for that to 0 after finishing/starting with a new file. -_-' But anyway, thanks alot for the help Tim. Much appriciated!

Comment: @Felix did you fix the issue?

Comment: @Mohammadabumazen so far so good. It seems to be working correctly.